# How to print image displayed in ImageView in android Studio

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a recyclerView which will display all images from JSON path and I used a click event that will display the clicked image to a new activity.

Now I want to print the image that is displayed. I have put a print button in the activity and while clicking on the print button i should get image to be printed in the network printer. I have used the below code. but I am getting error in `getActivity()` .

```
Button print = findViewById(R.id.print);
        //imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled( true );


        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
                photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
                //Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(  );
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                photoPrinter.printBitmap("test print",bitmap);
            }
        });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Activity.this` instead of `getActivity()` where `Activity` is the name of your Activity.

The method `getActivity()` is used when you want to reference `Fragments`. But here you have an activity so there is an error! You have to do something like this:

```
//Other code
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(YourJavaClassName.this);
//Other code
```

Please be sure to change `YourJavaClassName` to your activity's class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getapplicationcontext() method or YourCurrentActivityName.this